# How do I create a bash script, using loops, to create a Multiplication Table with 5 column/10 row format

Tags: bash, loops, row, multiple-columns, multiplication

Here is what I have:

```
#!/bin/bash

#create a multiplication table 5 columns 10 rows
echo "        Multiplication Table   "
echo "-----+-------------------------"
for x in {0..5}
do
    for  y in {0..10}
    do
        echo -n "$(( $x * $y )) "
    done
    echo
echo "-----+--------------------------"
done
```

This is my Output:

```
     Multiplication Table
-----+-------------------------
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
-----+--------------------------
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10
-----+--------------------------
0 2 4 6 8 10 12 14 16 18 20
-----+--------------------------
0 3 6 9 12 15 18 21 24 27 30
-----+--------------------------
0 4 8 12 16 20 24 28 32 36 40
-----+--------------------------
0 5 10 15 20 25 30 35 40 45 50
-----+--------------------------
```

This is the Needed Output:

```
             Multiplication Table
----+-------------------------------------
    |   0       1       2       3       4
----+-------------------------------------
0   |   0       0       0       0       0
1   |   0       1       2       3       4
2   |   0       2       4       6       8
3   |   0       3       6       9       12
4   |   0       4       8       12      16
5   |   0       5       10      15      20
6   |   0       6       12      18      24
7   |   0       7       14      21      28
8   |   0       8       16      24      32
9   |   0       9       18      27      36
----+-------------------------------------
```

I've tried to write this many different ways, but I'm struggling with finding a way to format it correctly. The first is pretty close, but I need it to have the sequential numbers being multiplied on the top and left side. I'm not sure how to use, or if I can use, the **seq** command to achieve this or if there is a better way. I also need to have straight columns and rows with the defining lines setting the table layout, but my looking up the **column** command hasn't produced the right output.

Here was my final output and code:

```
#!/bin/bash
#create a multiplication table 5 columns 10 rows

#Create top of the table
echo "      Multiplication Table"
echo "----+------------------------------"

#Print the nums at top of table and format dashes
echo -n "    |"; printf '\t%d' {0..5}; echo
echo "----+------------------------------"

#for loops to create table nums
for y in {0..9}
do  
    #Print the side nums and |  
    echo -n "$y   |"
    #for loop to create x 
    for x in {0..5}
    do 
    #Multiply vars, tab for spacing    
        echo -en "\t$((x*y))"
    done
    #Print
    echo
done
#Print bottom dashes for format
echo "----+------------------------------"
```

I changed a bit of Armali's code just to make it more appealing to the eye, and the echo was moved to the bottom (out of the loop) so it didn't print as many lines. But again, thank you Armali, as I would've spent a lot more time figuring out exactly how to write that printf code to get the format correct.

Comment: Take a look at `printf`. Formatting your output should help a lot with the layout.

Comment: Thank you very much Poshi, will do! printf was listed but I haven't done any C-style scripting yet, although I'll look into it further. Thank you for the response and help of a direction!

Comment: Instead of appending your solution to the question, you should post it as an answer; this way you might even get reputation points for it.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm not sure how to use, or if I can use, the **seq** command to achieve this …

`seq` offers no advantage here over `bash`'s *sequence expression* combined with `printf`.

This variant of your script produces (with the usual 8-column tabs) the needed output:

```
#!/bin/bash
#create a multiplication table 5 columns 10 rows
echo "             Multiplication Table"
echo "----+-------------------------------------"
echo -n "    |"; printf '\t%d' {0..4}; echo
echo "----+-------------------------------------"
for y in {0..9}
do  echo -n "$y   |"
    for x in {0..4}
    do  echo -en "\t$((x*y))"
    done
    echo
    echo "----+-------------------------------------"
done
```

Comment: Thank you Armali, I'll run that against what I did last night, but thank you for putting in such an effort on my behalf. I understand from python that \t = tab and \n = new line?, but what is the '\t%d' {0..4} echo line do? Thanks again and I'll post my attempt shortly, so if you have any constructive criticism... it would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I got this... so the echo -n (contains all on one line) "    |" prints my  line character or pipe; printf '\t%d {0..4} (are the top row of numbers); ??? Then in the for loops you use the same type format and tabs between numbers, yes?

Comment: @Thumper77 - Right, the `'\t%d'` is the _format_ for [`printf`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/printf.html) (meaning each _argument_ is to be printed as a decimal number preceded by a tab), while the `{0..4}` expands to `0 1 2 3 4`. And yes, in the loop the `echo` also uses a tab (the option `-e` is needed to translate the `\t`).